# How to set the background color of the selected tab in PagerTiltleStrip

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, viewpagerindicator

I trying to change the color of the selected tab in PagerTitleStrip, I was able to change the color of the entire strip. But that is not what I wanted.

How to achieve this? Can any one help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out! Considered PagerTabStrip instead of PagerTitleStrip.

```
tabStrip = (MyPagerTabStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
            tabStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240, 240, 240));
            tabStrip.getChildAt(1).setPadding(30, 15, 30, 15);
            tabStrip.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_orange);
            tabStrip.setDrawFullUnderline(false);
            tabStrip.setTabIndicatorColor(Color.rgb(240,240,240));
```

Took one day to research on it!

Comment: @user1327911: can we do like this also, see this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35403672/set-the-height-of-title-of-pagertabstrip

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with PagerTitleStrip too.

1. Implement **ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener** in your main activity
2. Put **setOnPageChangeListener** for your ViewPager

   MyViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
3. Then overrride methods
   onPageScrolled,
   onPageSelected,
   onPageScrollStateChanged

we just need to put our code in **onPageSelected(int position)** method
like if you have 5 pages, however beforthat you need 
- Declare pagerTitleStrip in your main code.

```
    PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip;
```

- And in onCreateMethod

  ```
  PagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.title);
  ```
- R.id.title is the id  of pagerTitleStrip in main_layout

  ```
  if(position==0){
      pagerTitleStrip.setBackgroundColor(0xFF3D0201);
  }
  if(position==1){
      pagerTitleStrip.setBackgroundColor(0xFF013E10);
  }
  if(position==2){
      pagerTitleStrip.setBackgroundColor(0xFF242F52);
  }
  if(position==3){
      pagerTitleStrip.setBackgroundColor(0xFF60611D);
  }
  if(position==4){
      pagerTitleStrip.setBackgroundColor(0xFF5E2E52);
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to use `PagerTitleStrip` and not `PagerTabStrip` all you have to do is below.

```
tabStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title_strip);
            tabStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(240, 240, 240));
            tabStrip.getChildAt(1).setPadding(30, 15, 30, 15);
            tabStrip.getChildAt(1).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_orange);
```

This will allow you to set the background color of the middle tab and will not show a tab indicator, like `PagerTabStrip`.

Comment: I want to change the color of the text when it is selected & that I am doing in ViewPager's onPageSelected method but when I call pagerTitleStrip.getChildCount()); I am getting value 3 but I have 4 titles in the list. Because of this reason I am not able to solve my problem.